# Enable python autocompletion in Vim without any install

Tags: python, linux, vim

I am coding Python3 in Vim and would like to enable autocompletion.

I must use different computers without internet access. Every computer is running Linux with Vim preinstalled.

I dont want to have something to install, I just want the simplest way to enable python3 completion (even if it is not the best completion), just something easy to enable from scratch on a new Linux computer.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have compiled vim with `+python3`, you can try omnifunc.
Add following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
au FileType python setl ofu=python3complete#Complete
```

Then in insert mode, just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>.

See `:help omnifunc`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Vim, by default doesn't do what you want, you are pretty much limited to the Ctrl-P style, which is better than it seems once you get used to it.

However i also often find myself working on machines that are not allowed to access the internet or have other files placed on them and When i find myself in this situation and i am using an unfamiliar language i sometimes use Vim's dictionary completion: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip91

To populate this dictionary i cat / trim / filter the man pages for the language to get a variety of keywords. I ram these into a filetype specific dictionary: `au FileType * execute 'setlocal dict+=~/.vim/words/'.&filetype.'.txt'`

Obviously this isn't the greatest solution and it is a bit heavy handed but it does provide a certain degree of "What is that function called" type stuff.

Answer (score 0):

by default, Ctrl-P in insert mode do an autocompletion with all the words already present in the file you're editing

Comment: Yes actually I am already using that but I just wanted to know if there is a more Python oriented grammar completion by default in Vim.

So I guess the answer is No ?